# Android Program Flow Help

Tags: android

Consider the following:

I have three packages:

package.a
package.b
package.c

Each package contains a class and an activity

package.a>>activity.a>>class.a
package.b>>activity.b>>class.b
package.c>>activity.c>>class.c

I am assembling all of these together into one application and I want activity.c to be the first activity in the stack. In other words, I want it to run first. Do I simply modify the order in the manifest? What initializes the first application and what sets their corresponding order? After the first activity is started can I just go back and forth with intents?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` intent filter on the activity you want to be launched when the application starts.

[From the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html):

> CATEGORY_LAUNCHER The activity can be the initial activity of a task and is listed in the top-level application launcher.

Once the application is started, you can move back and forth using intents.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your activity C with this `intent filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This way that will be the only activity launched from the home screen.